# Android studio preview doesnt match the real screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, preview

Im developing some table in android studio.

this is the relevant part of my layout:

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <TableLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:stretchColumns="0"
            android:shrinkColumns="1"   android:background="#ffffff">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="25dp"
                android:text="טבלת בית א"
                android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                android:id="@+id/tableA" />
            <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="-"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t01" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="קבוצה"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t02" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="משח'"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t03" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="ניצ'"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t04" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="תיקו"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t05" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="הפס'"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t06" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="יחס שערים"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t07" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="הפרש"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t08" />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="נק'"
                    android:background="#00ccff"
                    android:textColor="#fafafa"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t09" />

            </TableRow>
            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="1"  android:layout_span="1"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t11" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text="הפועל מערכות מידע"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t12"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="6"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t13"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="5"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t14"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="1"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t15"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t16"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="22-12"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t17"
                    android:layout_column="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="8"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t18"
                    android:layout_column="7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="23"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t19"
                    android:layout_column="8" />

            </TableRow>



            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t21"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t22"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="ליגת"
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t23"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t24"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t25"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t26"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t27"
                    android:layout_column="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t28"
                    android:layout_column="7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t29"
                    android:layout_column="8" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp" android:text="3"  android:layout_span="1"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t31" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t32"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t33"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="הכדורגל"
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t34"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t35"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t36"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t37"
                    android:layout_column="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t38"
                    android:layout_column="7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#f0f0f0"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t39"
                    android:layout_column="8" />

            </TableRow>


            <TableRow
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="4"
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t41"
                    android:layout_column="0" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t42"
                    android:layout_column="1" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t43"
                    android:layout_column="2" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t44"
                    android:layout_column="3" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="מיד"
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t45"
                    android:layout_column="4" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t46"
                    android:layout_column="5" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t47"
                    android:layout_column="6" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t48"
                    android:layout_column="7" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text=""
                    android:background="#FFE5E5E5"
                    android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:id="@+id/t49"
                    android:layout_column="8" />
            </TableRow>

            </TableRow>
        
        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

my problem is:

the preview that i see on android studio doesnt match at all what my real phone shows.

my preview is for andoird API 22, and so is my phone, and i checked the size of my preview and it feets as well my screen size.

this is what the preview looks like:
[image]

and this is how my real phone looks like:
[image]

any suggestions? i just want my app to look like the preview
(im talking of course about the second column)

Comment: try to use emulator or android phone ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use new line character in string declare it in string.xml

```
                <string name="mystring">הפועל  1\ מערכות 2\ מידע</string>
```

and then use like this

```
               <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:text="@string/mystring"
                android:background="#f0f0f0"
                android:textColor="#5c5c5c"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:id="@+id/t12"
                android:layout_column="1" />
```

[it will look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/So85z.png)

Answer (score 1):

Android Studio preview is just for our understanding. You have to use an emulator or your own device to test your application. Best results can get on device.

Comment: thank you. so any suggestions how to make my app look like the preview?

Answer (score 0):

> i tried your code. Now Looking like this

[image]

Comment: very strange, any idea what on my phone it looks like that? i have sony xperia m2

Comment: post screenshot of your phone of this screen

Comment: ita under "realphone" title in my post